# Uniform convergence of a function series

Tags: proof-verification, uniform-convergence

I am trying to understand a proof of Weierstrass M-test stated as

"If $|u_k(x)|\leq a_k$ for all $x\in M$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges, then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty u_k(x)$ konverges uniformly on $M$."

My attempt to prove the theorem goes like this:

Since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges there is to every number $\epsilon>0$ a number $N>0$ such that whenever $n\geq N$ we have

$$|\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k - \sum_{k=1}^n a_k| = |\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k| = \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k < \epsilon$$

Thus, for $n\geq N$,

$$|\sum_{k=1}^\infty u_k(x) - \sum_{k=1}^n u_k(x)| = |\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty u_k(x)| \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty |u_k(x)| \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k < \epsilon$$

for all $x\in M$.

This was my attempt. However, the proof I am looking at wants to first show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty u_k(x)$ converges pointwise to a sum $s(x)$, and then show that when $n\geq N$ then $|s(x) - s_n(x)| < \epsilon$. Is this really necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is wrong, since you mention $\sum_{k=1}^\infty u_k(x)$ without having proved that this series converges.

Comment: Could you clarify why that is a problem? In my understanding one uses the notation $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$ both for the series (whether it converges or not), and for the number to which it converges (if it converges).

Comment: @jock.marshall But when you write $\left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty u_k(x)-\sum_{k=1}^nu_k(x)\right|\leqslant\cdots$ this can only mean the number to which it converges, and this assumes that it converges.